# Remote debug with Eclipse PDT

Tags: php, eclipse, docker, xdebug

I am trying to configure a debugging environment.

I have a server on 192.168.200.58 where a PHP API is running.

I would like to know if it's possible to set up Eclipse to remotely debug the php code executed when i call the API.

I use Docker and Compose to deploy the app.

I added this to `docker-compose.yml` :

```
environnement:
    XDEBUG_CONFIG: "remote_host=192.168.1.138"
    PHP_IDE_CONFIG: "serverName=Test"
```

And this to `conf/php.ini` :

```
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_host=$MY_LOCAL_IP
```

I have Xdebug and Zend Debugger on PHP>Debug>Debugger on Eclipse with :

`Accept remote session JIT = any`

I'm stuck at the PHP>Servers configuration in Eclipse (i named it Test as the name in Docker) : what URL do i put ? Which Document Root (if it's remote i don't access it?) ? Is that how i should proceed ?

Thanks for your help